# Matplotlib legend plotting name data title multiple times

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting some data from a CSV. I recently edited the date range of the CSV file but the values are the same. Before, the data was being plotted simulatiously with 2 other data sets, and the legend had only one entry for this data set. After editing the CSV file, the legend now displays the label 3 times but overall graphs the data correctly. I have tried removing the other two data sets from the plot, using numpoints=1, and ensuring nothing is in a for loop (which none of this code uses one). Additionally, I made sure there wasn't 3 versions of the data saved in the same directory. Any suggestions on why this is happening and how to fix it? I'm including my plotting code in case something is in it that is wrong.

```
plt.plot(date_range,ice_extent1,color='red',label='MASIE')
plt.xlabel("Date (yyyy/mm)")
plt.ylabel("Sea Ice Extent (10^6 km^2)")
plt.title("Sea Ice Extent")`
plt.legend()
```

Comment: could you give a sample of the csv file and how you read the data?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Without a runnable code one cannot know what goes wrong.